# Input TAG inside table, css classes are not working at all

Tags: css, input, html-table, user-agent

I'm creating a **complex form** that a player will use to save his own personal character sheet via database.
For this I'm using a lot of **Input** TAGs and for the Layout I'm using **tables** to help me set it up easy and in orthogonal way.

For the input I'm uses classes that modify their **height**, **width** and **text-align**.

**HTML**

```
<div id="a_ability" class="advanced">
  <h3>Advanced</h3>
    <table id="tab02" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Ability</th>
        <th scope="col">Temp Value</th>
        <th id="tab02" scope="col">Bonus</th>
        <th scope="col">Magic Obj</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Strenght</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="temp_str" class="50x50"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bonus_str" class="50x50"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mag_str" class="50x200"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Dexterity</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="temp_dex" class="50x50"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="bonus_dex" class="50x50"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="mag_dex" class="50x200"></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.50x50 {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
text-align: center;
}
.50x200{
height: 50px;
width: 190px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

The result of this is like that the class **do not apply at all** on the tag. The dimension are default one and I can apply only if I apply an ID for every input (the work will be impossibly long) or **sometimes** if I apply the **!important** attribute (but only work with some css rules).

I'm working on **Dreamweaver** (if you know the program) when I'm on *"Design view"* without the "Live" option enbled, everything seems fine, but when I put the design view On the input are **wrongly formatted**.

I've checked:

- I have not any **css conflict** (for example one rule that overwrite another one)
- I have checked the "inspection" inside Chrome (for example) and the input take a widht are of 183px from apparently nowhere

Is it could be some **user agent stylesheet** of the browser?
Because when I open the inspection element in Chrome there is this line:

```
width: 84px;
   .advanced table tr td - 50px
```

it get's from the css the 50px, **but where it gets the 84px**?? There is no rule at all with that value!

How can I solve this?

**I add more information**

Here is the JSFiddle link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr9Vx/) and you can see that it's not working the styling of the input.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JSFiddle your code. Also, Dreamweaver's design view is unreliable.

Comment: Try changing your class names [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Comment: If I JsFilddle my code the same things happens. The css do not modify the input inside the table. But If I apply an ID to them, it will.

Comment: So add the link to jsfiddle

Comment: ok I have added the Jsfiddle link.. I don't know what I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create `class` or `id` starting with numbers...

See your fiddle with an extra `i` (the letter doesn't matters)
**http://jsfiddle.net/Sr9Vx/1/**

**Edit**:
I just see the link that **@Trey** give's you in his comment ([Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors))  there you can find a few explanations & link's with the reason and even better link's with official references.

Example:
http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-css3-syntax-20030813/#characters
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Good luck with your proyect.

Comment: Oh.. Thak you very much! When I've changed the classes all the project.. just "fixed" himself.. Thak you very much! I didn't knew that somethig so little and so stupid could me give such an headheache!